# PHP - Notice: Undefined index: $_SESSION['login'] on header.php

Tags: php

I'm having this error on my header.php which has all the html/bootstrap for my navigation bar.

```
<?php
        if($_SESSION['login']) {
        ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <p class="navbar-text">Hello, <?php $name; ?></p>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

It keeps showing on my navigation bar but it works fine:

> "Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel-sys\includes\header.php on line 36"

It just keeps showing that notice. How can I solve it?

Comment: it means 'login' is not set. you can check like this if(isset($_SESSION['login']))

Answer (score 1):

First you should check session variable has been started or not

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have `session_start()` in the top of your page and replace

```
<?php 

 if($_SESSION['login']) {
 ... 
 }
?>
```

by this

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login']) 
 {
 ...
 }
?>
```

Comment: no need for second condition. $_SESSION['login']

Comment: depends , if he sets `login` to true if user is logged in and false when logged out , its needed

Answer (score 1):

You can try the updated code as below.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <p class="navbar-text">Hello, <?php $name; ?></p>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```